# loading mps to pdf converter latex

Tags: header-footer, numbering, theorems, page-numbering, fancyhdr

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english,openright]{book}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layaureo}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{dsfont}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\addtolength{\headheight}{15pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth {#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,L]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
%\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%\addtolenght{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}

\linespread{1.1}


\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norma}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\newcommand{\numberset}{\mathbb}
\newcommand{\N}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\newcommand{\D}{\numberset{D}}

%\theoremstyle{definition}
%\newtheorem{definizione}{Definizione}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}{Osservazione}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollario}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definizione}[chapter]

\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
%\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
%\newtheorem{propos}{Proposizione}
%\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
%\newtheorem{cor}{Corollario}
\newtheorem{esempio}{Esempio}



\usepackage{subfigure}

\title{Introduction to Markov Reneval}
\author{Davide Cherubini}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Introduction to Markov Reneval}
\section{Homogeneous Convolution}

We consider two continous random variables F and G where $F,G\in\mathbb{R}$ with density function f and g  respectively.

Convolution is a mathematical operation between f and g, producing a third function  that is typically viewed as a modified version of one of the original functions and it is defined as the integral of the product of the two functions after one is reversed and shifted.


Then,
\[f\bullet g(t)
\]

is a homogeneous convolution with the following properties:
```

where is the error???

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If I add `\end{document}` at the end I get no error. The message you quote in the title is just information about something LaTeX had done and not an error message. There *is* an error, though: it's “renewal”, not ”reneval”.

Answer (score 4):

I think the building process got stuck in an infinite loop, and the last thing it was shown to be doing was "Loading MPS to PDF converter". So stop the process and find the source of the endless loop. In my case it was a lapsus like `\newcommand{\maal}{\maal}`, which was obviously not what I had in mind.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.